# How to Put a function with two parameters in a Array (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, function

I have:

```
function val(a,z){
   return a/2, z+8;
}

val(3,4);
```

Put this result:

```
 x = 1,5
 y = 12
```

in a Array;

```
[x,y];
```

Thanks.

Comment: But what is the problem? Why you cant just return the value of `val()` function as array? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return multiple variables in an array then just add [] to your return statement.

```
function val(a,z){
   return [a/2, z+8];
}
//then , the first array element is the x, second one is y
//var a = val(4,6)
//a[0] = 2  <- x
//a[1] = 14 <- y
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to return as object

Like this

```
function val(a, z) {
    return {
        x: a / 2,
        y: z + 8
    };
}
var data = val(3, 4);
console.log(data.x);
console.log(data.y);
```